# Prolog and List Unification

Tags: prolog, unification, prolog-anonymous-variable

I'm trying to further my understanding of Prolog, and how it handles unification. In this case, how it handles unification with lists.

This is my knowledgebase;

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|T]):- member(X, T).
```

If I'm understanding the process correctly. If `member(X, [X|_])` is not true, then it moves into the recursive rule, and if `X` is in list `T`, then `[_|T]` is unified with `T`.

So what happens to the anonymous variable in my recursive predicate? Does it get discarded? I'm having difficulty understanding the exact unification process with lists, as `[_|T]` is two variables, rather than one. I'm just trying to figure out how the unification process works precisely with lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that `_`  is `Y`

```
member(X, [Y|T]):- member(X, T).
```

Then this is `True` regardless `Y`. Now you are "returning" `member(X, T)`. In other words, you are discarding `Y` and "returning" `member(X, T).`

`_` means, whatever it is, ignore that variable.

> The _ is just like any other variable, except that each one you see is
>   treated as a different variable and Prolog won't show you what it
>   unifies with. There's no special behavior there; if it confuses you
>   about the behavior, just invent a completely new variable and put it
>   in there to see what it does.

In your case, your function check if a given element exists on a list, so,  you take first element of the list, check if is equal, if not, you discard that element and moves on.

Comment: I know where I went wrong, now. For some reason, due to the way the rule was written, I was reading it right to left, instead of left to right. No idea why.

Comment: @MartynShutt: To understand the meaning of rules, in particular recursive rules, reading them right-to-left is definitely the better way!

Answer (score 2):

I think your primary question of how lists are represented as variables has been adequately answered, but I sense there are some other aspects to Prolog that need clarification.

To understand Prolog predicates and clauses, it's a good idea not to think of them as "functions" that "return" things, even metaphorically. It can lead you down the dark path of imperative thinking in Prolog. :)

In considering the predicate:

```
(1) member(X, [X|_]).
(2) member(X, [_|T]) :- member(X, T).
```

Think of `member/2` as a *relation* which describes when element `X` is a member of the list `L`, and the clauses are the rules for determining when it is true.

I'll assume that you already know about how lists are represented in Prolog based upon other answers (*e.g.*, Will Ness' detailed answer).

The first clause says:

(1) *`X` is a member of `[X|_]` regardless of what the tail of the list `[X|_]` is*

In that notation, the variable `_` represents the tail of list `[X|_]` and `X` represents the first element of that list. It's trivially true that `X` is a member of this list, so `member(X, [X|_]).` is a fact. It's true regardless of what the tail of the list is, so we just use `_` (an anonymous variable) since this rule doesn't need the information. Prolog doesn't technically "throw the value away" but the programmer throws it away because the programmer isn't using it. If we had, instead, said, `member(X, [X|T]).` that would work fine, but we're not using `T`. Prolog might instantiate it, but it wouldn't be used. It's like assigning `x = 3` in C but not using it's value. In this case, Prolog will indicate a warning about a "singleton" variable. Watch for those, because it often means you misspelled something or forgot something. :)

The next rule is recursive. It says:

(2) *`X` is a member of list `[_|T]` **if** `X` is a member of the tail (`T`) of that list, regardless of what the first element of the list is*

Here we're considering the less trivial case where the first element in the list may not be a match to `X`, so the truth value of `member(X, L)` depends, in this rule, upon the truth value of `member(X, T)` where `T` is the tail (everything but the first element) of `L`. The rule **does not** unify `member(X, [_|T])` with `member(X, T)`, so it **does not** unify `T` with `[_|T]` as you might suppose. The `:-` operator defines a rule or implication (note the *if* in the rule description). [*N.B.*, If you were to *unify* these terms, it would be done with with the *unification* operator, `=/2`: `member(X, [_|T]) = member(X, T)`].

On the recursive query `member(X, T)`, Prolog goes back to the top, the first rule, and attempts to unify the first argument `X` with the head of the second argument (which is the original list minus its first element, or *head*) and, if it doesn't match, goes to rule #2 again, continually checking the tail as well, until it can unify. If it gets to the point where the tail is empty (`[]`) and hasn't been able to unify `X` with any elements, the predicate fails because there are no facts or rules that match `member(X, [])`. However, if it does unify `X` with an element, it *succeeds* (it **does not** "return a value* in the sense that a function would in other languages) and reveals the values of any variables it instantiated in the arguments in the process, or simply will succeed if all the arguments passed are already instantiated. If there are more rules to check after succeeding (there was what's called a *choice point*), it will (if you tell it to) go back and check for more solutions and, if it finds them, display them as well. Or display `no` or `false` if there are no more.

Looking at an example query, *is `b` a member of `[a,b,c]`*?

```
member(b, [a,b,c]).
```

Prolog will first try to unify the query with a *fact* or the *head* of a predicate. The first one it finds is:

```
member(X, [X|_]).
```

In attempting to unify, `X = b`, but `[a,b,c]` (or, `[a|[b,c]]` in the head-tail notation) doesn't unify with [b|_]`(note the head elements`a`and`b` mismatch). Prolog then moves on to the next clause:

```
member(X, [_|T]) :- member(X, T).
```

In unifying `member(b, [a,b,c])` with the head, it comes up with:

```
member(b, [_|[b,c]]) :- member(b, [b,c]).
```

It now has the recursive query to chase down: `member(b, [b,c])`. Since it's a new query, it starts at the top again and attempts to unify this with `member(X, [X|_])`. Now, it's successful, because `member(b, [b,c])` (or, `member(b, [b|[c]])`) matches this pattern: `member(b, [b|_])`.

Therefore, the `member(b, [a,b,c]).` succeeds and Prolog will return "true". However, it's not done yet because it left what's called a *choice point*. Even though it matched `member(b, [b,c])` with the first clause, it will still want to go back and find more cases that make it succeed, and there's still another clause to pursue. So, Prolog will go back and try `member(b, [b,c])` against the second clause, matching `member(b, [b|[c]])` to `member(b, [_|[c]])` and doing another recursive query, `member(b, [c])` and so on until it ultimately fails to find another solution. This is why the query looks something like this:

```
| ?- member(b, [a,b,c]).

true ? ;

no
| ?-
```

It first succeeds, but then we ask for more (with `;`) and it then fails (`no`). This confuses some Prolog beginners, but it's because we've asked Prolog to get another solution, and it said there are none.

Because Prolog continues to try to find solutions (upon request), you can also use a variable in the query:

```
member(E, [a,b,c]).
```

This query runs the same way as the prior example, but now I have a variable as the first argument. Prolog will successfully match this to the first clause: `member(E, [a,b,c])` unifies with `member(X, [X|_])` via `E = a`. So you'll see something like:

```
| ?- member(E, [a,b,c]).

E = a ?
```

If we now ask for more solutions with `;`, Prolog goes back and attempts the second clause, unifying `member(E, [a|[b,c]])` with `member(X, [_|T])` yielding `_ = a` (which is ignored in the predicate) and `T = [b,c]`. It then recursively queries, `member(E, [b,c])` and, since it's a new query, goes back to the top and matches `member(X, [X|_])` again, this time with `E = b`. So we see:

```
| ?- member(E, [a,b,c]).

E = a ? ;

E = b ?
```

And so on. `member(E, [a,b,c])` will find all the values of `E` which make `member(E, [a,b,c])` true and then finally fail after exhausting all the elements of `[a,b,c]`).

Comment: I had to read your post twice before this sunk in, but this has really cleared up unification for me. Prolog is such a different way of thinking, and while I've long gotten over attempting to draw any parallels with declarative programming, that mindset still lingers, so it really helps to understand, step by step, exactly how Prolog performs proof search using unification.

I'll probably come back to this post a couple more times until it becomes intuitive as I work my way through new problems.

Comment: @MartynShutt I'm glad it helped. I always tell new Prolog users to forget just about everything they learned programming in another language and treat it like it's your very first programming experience. :) There are times when one must use Prolog in an imperative way, but it's a great exercise to step firmly away from that mindset when learning the language.

Comment: yes, it helped immensely. The learning curve is steeper than I'm used to with other languages I've learned, but having to think about problems in such a different way to what I'm used to also makes it very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

A list is just a compound term with the `'.'` functor:

```
1 ?- [_|T] = .(_,T).
true.

2 ?- [_|T] =.. X.
X = ['.', _G2393, T].
```

The usual process of structural unification of compound terms apply:

```
3 ?- [A|T] = .(B,R). 
A = B,
T = R.
```

`[A|T]` is really `.(A,T)` so the functors (`.`) and the arities (both terms are binary, of arity 2) match, so the respective constituents are matched as well.

Yes, the anonymous variable `_` is ignored for the purposes of reporting the unification results. Otherwise it is just a fresh uniquely named variable.

> it moves into the recursive rule, and if X is in list T, then [_|T] is unified with T.

Not quite. The unification happens *before* the "moving on", as part of the clause selection. To unify a list `L` with `[_|T]` is to select its "tail" and have `T` referring to it. E.g.

```
4 ?- L = [1,2,3], L = [_|T].
L = [1, 2, 3],
T = [2, 3].
```

(`_` is `1` but is not reported).

Comment: Although this doesn't address my problem specifically, your answer is very helpful and in-depth. I never knew lists were just another type of functor.

Comment: of compound terms, more correctly. functor is a part of a compound term, along with the arguments. You asked about unification for lists, and I tried to answer that.

Comment: It was a very detailed answer. It just so happened that all my confusion in this particular instance derived from reading the rule back-to-front, probably because of the symmetry of the rule, but your answer has taught me a few things as well.

Answer (score 1):

`[A|B]` represents a list where A is the Head element and B is the whole rest list.

So to explain you the algorithm shortly:

1. Clause: If X is the first element of the list the predicate succeeds.
2. Clause: If that's not the case, we try to find X in the tail of the list. Therefore, we call member recursively but instead of passing the whole list we now pass the list EXCEPT the head element. In other words, we walk through the list step by step always looking at the head element first. If that is not our element, we dig further.

Think of the anonymous variable `_` just as a variable you do not need later. The algorithm would also work, if you replaced `_` by a capital letter, however it would give you a warning that you named a variable that you never use.